# Does target order in kernel build makefiles matter?

Tags: makefile, kernel

This first line of my arch/arm/mach-omap2/Makefile is

```
# Common support
obj-y := id.o io.o control.o mux.o devices.o serial.o gpmc.o timer-gp.o
```

but it is being ignored by the kernel build system. Only when I move this line to the end of the file do the targets get built. Could another line in the Makefile override the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Look for another line that assigns a different value to `obj-y`. If you don't find one, try moving that line to the *middle* of the makefile, and see if the targets get built; from there you can do a binary search.

Comment: You're right!
obj-$(CONFIG_OMAP_IOMMU) := iommu2.o omap-iommu.o
Must be a bug in the Makefile. CONFIG_OMAP_IOMMU was always n before so the problem didn't show up. Changed : to + resolved the problem. Thanks!